# Not able to send mail from java mail APi from GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email using Java mail Api, and my application is deployed on google App engine,

Earlier i was able to send email from my java code but recently it has stopped,

Bellow is the error

`javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuq
534-5.7.14 szPbAPjs-PmJgBd5xmPAVgRB8-3WxkoQy7WaGBIGRyltJO9LxKnw0oagw1e-jZeQcgABnK
534-5.7.14 mcxSUPyD4ohtBPkovBS45tnMElRdeWM7mzfw2wU3vqqQpDw7_8Z9rphQR_SZpR> Please
534-5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 186sm22205348pfb.99 - gsmtp`

I have done everything, added gmail Account in IAM as owner enabled lesssecure option in gmail, but still I am getting the same error

Here is the code

```
public static void sendWelcomeMail(String msg,String email,String subject) {
         System.out.println("Starte - "+email);
       final String username = "serv*******@gmail.com";
       final String password = "********";

       Properties prop = new Properties();
       prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

       Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                   }
               });

       try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
           message.setRecipients(
                   Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   InternetAddress.parse(email+", fo*********@gmail.com")
           );
           message.setSubject(subject);
           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); //1
        // Create the HTML Part
        BodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); //4
        htmlBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html"); //5

        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart); // 6
        // Set the Multipart's to be the email's content
        message.setContent(multipart); //7 

           Transport.send(message);

           System.out.println("Done");
       }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

But from my local machine I am able to send email.
let me know what I am doing wrong.

TIA

Comment: There seems to be a [dedicated API for sending emails from GMail accounts via GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/). Why not use that?

Comment: After Adding this lines it works fine
 `message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, " Admin"));`
and
`new InternetAddress("fo***********@gmail.com", "")`

Comment: Would you mind editing your post in order to include the working code?

Comment: Yes I will update post

Answer (score 1):

So here are the changes I used to solve the problem.

I changed this part of the code:

```
message.setRecipients(
                   Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   InternetAddress.parse(email+", fo*********@gmail.com")
       );
```

to this:

```
message.addRecipient(
                   Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   new InternetAddress(email, "")
           );
```

And this other part of the code from this:

`message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));`

to this:

`message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, "Admin"));`

As a result here is the complete code:

```
public static void sendWelcomeMail(String msg,String email,String subject) {
       final String username = "ser******@gmail.com";
       final String password = "**********";

       Properties prop = new Properties();
       prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
       prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

       Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                       return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                   }
               });

       try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
           message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, "Admin"));
           message.addRecipient(
                   Message.RecipientType.TO,
                   new InternetAddress(email, "")
           );
           message.addRecipient(
                   Message.RecipientType.CC,
                   new InternetAddress("fo********@gmail.com", "")
           );
           message.setSubject(subject);
           Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(); //1
        // Create the HTML Part
        BodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); //4
        htmlBodyPart.setContent(msg, "text/html"); //5

        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart); // 6
        // Set the Multipart's to be the email's content
        message.setContent(multipart); //7 

           Transport.send(message);

           System.out.println("Done");
       }catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Exception in sending mail - "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```